# How to set EventhubNamespace TLS version to 1.2 by TypeScript

Tags: typescript, azure, namespaces, tls1.2, azure-eventhub

I have a requirement to upgrade eventhub's TLS version to 1.2.
And the event-hubs are created by typescript.
like this:

EventhubNamespaceService.ts

```
import { EventHubManagementClient } from '@azure/arm-eventhub';
export default class EventhubNamespaceService {
  client: EventHubManagementClient;

  constructor(client: EventHubManagementClient) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  async createNamespace(
    resourcegroupName: string,
    name: string,
    maximumThroughputUnits: number = 5,
    isAutoInflateEnabled: boolean = true,
    location: string = 'westeurope',
  ): Promise<EventhubNamespace> {
    const resp = await this.client.namespaces.createOrUpdate(resourcegroupName, name, {
      maximumThroughputUnits,
      isAutoInflateEnabled,
      location,
    });

    return {
      id: resp.id!,
      name: resp.name!,
      isAutoInflateEnabled: resp.isAutoInflateEnabled,
      maximumThroughputUnits: resp.maximumThroughputUnits,
      resourceGroup: resourcegroupName,
    };
  }
```

EventhubService.ts

```
import { EventHubManagementClient } from '@azure/arm-eventhub';
import { AccessRights as AzureAccessRights } from '@azure/arm-eventhub/esm/models';

export default class EventhubService {
  client: EventHubManagementClient;

  constructor(client: EventHubManagementClient) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  async eventhub(
    resourcegroupName: string,
    namespaceName: string,
    name: string,
  ): Promise<Eventhub> {
    const resp = await this.client.eventHubs.get(resourcegroupName, namespaceName, name);

    return {
      name: resp.name!,
      id: resp.id!,
      resourcegroupName,
      namespaceName,
      partitionCount: resp.partitionCount!,
      messageRetentionInDays: resp.messageRetentionInDays!,
    };
  }

  async createOrUpdateEventhub(
    resourcegroupName: string,
    namespaceName: string,
    name: string,
    messageRetentionInDays: number = 1,
    partitionCount: number = 1,
    consumerGroups?: string[],
    authorizationRules?: AuthorizationRuleInput[],
  ): Promise<Eventhub> {
    const resp = await this.client.eventHubs.createOrUpdate(
      resourcegroupName,
      namespaceName,
      name,
      {
        messageRetentionInDays,
        partitionCount,
      },
    );

    if (consumerGroups) {
      await toPromiseChain(consumerGroups, (cg) =>
        this.client.consumerGroups.createOrUpdate(resourcegroupName, namespaceName, name, cg, {
          name: cg,
        }),
      );
    }

    if (authorizationRules) {
      await toPromiseChain(authorizationRules, (rule) =>
        this.client.eventHubs.createOrUpdateAuthorizationRule(
          resourcegroupName,
          namespaceName,
          name,
          rule.name,
          {
            rights: rule.rights.map((r) => AccessRights[r] as AzureAccessRights),
            name,
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    return {
      id: resp.id!,
      name: resp.name!,
      resourcegroupName,
      namespaceName,
      messageRetentionInDays: resp.messageRetentionInDays!,
      partitionCount: resp.partitionCount!,
    };
  }
```

I couldn't find anywhere to add the TLS version related parameters. But it will create the evenhubs as TLS v1.0 as default. I don't know where to config it.
I also searched the [Microsoft learn website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-eventhub/namespaces?view=azure-node-latest).

How to config the TLS version that will create new event-hub as TLS 1.2 and update the old event-hubs from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please leverage the [minimumTlsVersion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/eventhub/resource-manager/Microsoft.EventHub/preview/2022-10-01-preview/namespaces-preview.json#L706) property of the EventHub and check if that helps ?

This property mentions the minimum TLS version for the cluster to support. The Accepted values are: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2.

More info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/arm-eventhub/src/models/mappers.ts#L2204) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/arm-eventhub/src/models/index.ts#L902).